# Vacuum permittivity and vacuum polarization

Tags: electromagnetism, vacuum, polarization, dielectric

Is vacuum permittivity an effect of vacuum polarization, or are these unrelated phenomena? A more detailed way to ask this might be, is the vacuum analagous to a dielectric in that electron-positron pairs arising in the vacuum weaken the strength of an electric field applied across the vacuum.?

Comment: "Weaken" the strength of an electric field *compared to what*?

Comment: The question may need to be re-worded but it seems that it may be about vacuum polarization, which is quite a sophisticated concept and perhaps doesn't deserve to be down voted.

Comment: The question is whether the permittivity of free space is considered to be the result of a physical phenomenon such as the polarization of virtual particles in free space, or is it just a constant needed to make units work out in the rmks measurement system. Is the permittivity of free space considered by physicists to have a cause, and if so, is that cause yet known?

Answer (score 3):

The permittivity of free space is not due to vacuum fluctuations, but it is affected by vacuum fluctuations.

The classical permittivity is a fundamental constant in the sense that the speed of light is a fundamental constant, and as such it is not *caused* by anything nor can its value be calculated and more than the speed of light can be calculated. However the permittivity of the QFT vacuum is [slightly different to the classical permittivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QED_vacuum#Electromagnetic_properties).